# Detect Cell at content offset

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that i need to detect which cell is in view.

I already have the content offset already using the code below:

```
float scrollPoint = self.collectionView.contentOffset.y;
```

now where i am stuck is at finding which cells are at that point.

How do I find out which cell(s) are at that point.

Comment: Are you talking about visible cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `- indexPathForItemAtPoint:(CGPoint)point`:

```
NSIndexPath* path = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:contentOffset];
if (path) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathForItemAtPoint:).

Actually, your `contentOffset` will give you the wrong cell.  You probably just want to use the point 0, 0 or whatever to get the cell that's at the left/top of the scrollview.